# Using queries in Dynamicloud I'm facing the following Exception: org.dynamicloud.api.RecordImpl cannot be cast

Tags: java, dynamic, cloud

**When I'm executing a query as follow:**

```
DynamicProvider<ContactForm> provider = new DynamicProviderImpl<ContactForm>(new RecordCredential(csk, aci));

Query<ContactForm> query = provider.createQuery(contactFormModel);
query.setOffset(0).setCount(1);

try {
    RecordResults<ContactForm> list = query.add(Conditions.like("namef", "ProBusiness%")).list();
    System.out.println("list = " + list.getFastReturnedSize());

if (list.getFastReturnedSize() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Contact Name = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getName());
    System.out.println("Contact Comments = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getComments());
}

} catch (DynamicloudProviderException e) {
    log.error("Error", e);
}
```

**I'm getting the next Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dynamicloud.api.RecordImpl cannot be cast to com.ContactForm
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dynamicloud has an general class to represent a record:**

```
public class RecordImpl implements Record
```

This class represents a record in Dynamicloud and is used if you don't indicate a BoundInstance's class to the model you're using in the query.

If you want a `RecordResults` with specific objects as follow:

```
RecordResults<ContactForm> list = query.add(Conditions.like("namef", "ProBusiness%")).list();
```

You have to set the BounceInstance's class (`ContactForm.class`) to the `RecordModel` object.

```
contactFormModel.setBoundClass(ContactForm.class);
```

Here you have a reference in Github about how to execute Queries in Dynamicloud:

[Query and RecordResults object](https://github.com/dynamicloud/dynamicloud_java_api#recordresults)

**Hope this helps!**